# array contains() method misbehaving

Tags: java, arrays, string, contains

I have the following Java method:

```
public boolean zonesAllAccountable(String messyZones)
{
    ArrayList<String> zonesAndLMS = getArrayListOfZones(messyZones);
    ArrayList<String> lmss = getArrayListOfLMSs(zonesAndLMS);
    for (LMSEntity lms : registeredLMSs) {
        if(!Arrays.asList(lmss).contains(lms.getLmsid()))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

What I am trying to do is ensure **all the strings** in the `lmss` ArrayList **equate to the `lmsid` property on one or any of the LMSEntity objects**.

I **think** the above should help me achieve that, but it is failing on the `.contains()` line. When I debug, it shouldn't go through to the return false, yet it does !

Comment: Why not use the [ArrayList#contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`.contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method directly on the `ArrayList`.  You can also explicitly return the boolean result back, without the need for `return true` or `return false`.

```
for (LMSEntity lms : registeredLMSs) {
    return !lmss.contains(lms.getLmsid());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error, but I'm not getting the behaviour I want, which means my logic was wrong :( Can you help with the method logic? If not, no worries ^_^

Comment: Can't do much about the logic in this question, sorry.  Goes outside of its scope.